# Powershell doesn't fill variable

Tags: powershell

I've got a Powershell script which is called with an argument that contains a file name. I want to strip the extension from the filename. This is the script:

```
param([string]$input_filename)
$inputFileNameOnly = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($input_filename) | Out-file "myfile.log" -Append
Write-Output "input filename without extension: " $inputFileNameOnly | Out-file "myfile.log" -Append
```

When I run the file:
.\myscript.ps1  "E:\Projectdata\Test book.html"

I can see that the call `[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($input_filename)` works: the first line in my log file is "Test book".

But nothing is placed after "input filename without extension: ". No value is assigned to variable $inputFileNameOnly.

What am I doing wrong here? There doesn't seem to be a type mismatch: `[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension` outputs a string.

I'm using Powershell 5 in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a little to fast with your pipes:

```
$inputFileNameOnly = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($input_filename) | Out-file "myfile.log" -Append
```

Those are two steps in one:
`[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($input_filename) | Out-file...` will get your value and write it to a file. However this action will not provide any output that can be captured in `$inputFileNameOnly`. `$inputFileNameOnly` is `$Null`.

Instead save the filename first in a variable and use that for the `Out-File`:

```
$inputFileNameOnly = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($input_filename) 
Out-file -InputObject $inputFileNameOnly -FilePath "myfile.log" -Append
```

Some cmdlets that don't provide output to the piple have the parameter `-PassThru` to force them sending something into the pipeline. Unfortunately `Out-File` doesn't.

Comment: That's it. Using pipes this way works in batch files (which I'm more familiar with than powershell).